# Расположение блоков в процентном соотношении относительно пространства

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Существуют ли какие-нибудь JS-решения для расположения блоков на странице в виде `Masonry`, но учитывая процентное отношение размера блока к общему размеру пространства? То есть, не высота или ширина в процентах, а именно весь размер блока, и все блоки таким образом комплектуются в виде `Masonry`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если я правильно понял вопрос то нужно что-то типа `webpack-bundle-analyzer` это реализуется библиотекой https://carrotsearch.com/foamtree/ рам разные формы и прямоугольники тоже и настраивается более менее, единственный минус - их лого во фришной версии

Comment: @DaniilLoban, да, именно такой функционал и нужен. Спасибо, буду разбираться. Лого пока не проблема.